# Can't position an hyperlink in my layout textview

Tags: android, layout, hyperlink

[Edit, this might show it better. Click this for the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtYk.png)

In my layout, I've lately added an information button in the top right. This caused all of my text to go upwards a bit. I downwarded that, but now the hyperlink that was in the bottom is gone. It's still there, but not shown cause the sizes or heights or something isn't correct. I've been changing sizes for hours now, everything changes but the link doesnt show up correctly..

The hyperlink is in a different textview as the other text. So it has to come right after the other. No scrollview is needed as the text is not that long.

Here are 2 pictures. The first one is how it was before, and how I want it again, with the hyperlink in the bottom. The second one is how it is now, with the new information image in the top right, resulting the hyperlink to be gone.
The "nieuws" button shouldnt be there. This is just to show where the hyperlink at the bottom should be.

[Click here to see the pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyXns.png)

This here is my xml code, textview2 is the one with the link, textview1 is the one with the text:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/btn_informatie" />
 </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bezoek"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide bezoektijden."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Main code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BezoekActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bezoek);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);


        HyperLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Text = Html.fromHtml(" <br />" +
        "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/bezoektijden'>Klik hier om de uitgebreide bezoektijden te bekijken.</a>");

        HyperLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        HyperLink.setText(Text);
    }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (v.getId()) {


                case R.id.button11:
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    break;
                case R.id.button12:
                    Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                    break;
                case R.id.button13:
                    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                    break;
                case R.id.button14:
                    Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                    break;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your frame layout and both `textview` in `linearlayout` and then add `weightsum` 1 to that `linearlayout`.so it will automatically shift your links(`linearlayout` with `buttons`) to the bottom of screen.

*Note - I have remove margin bottom from last text view and from your bottom linearlayout*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
         />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    />


</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Klik hier voor de uitgebreide bezoektijden."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***Result***

[image]

Comment: this made the buttons go upwards. The buttons are now where the hyperlink should be. The link itself is still not visible.

Comment: This made my buttons go upwards, where the link should be. The link is still not visible.

Comment: when you are talking about the link which control your are pointing here? @Koendebaas

Comment: Just the link that is shown on the second picture in my question. I want it to be above the buttons, under the other text. There is plenty of space for that. Just everytime either the buttons go upwards or below the screen, or the text goes downwards. The link itself is probably under the text and button view, not able to be shown.

Comment: I've added a new picture to the top, showing where i want the link to be, if that wasn't clear before. Check it out.

Comment: at one <LinearLayout line i get the following error:

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
 - The markup in the document following the root element must 
  be well-formed.

Comment: I think you havent copy well. @Koendebaas

Comment: It's kind off annoying because you deleted some of the main lines that involves my project. So if i copy your entire post i need to add all kinds of things that aren't in there

Comment: this is snippet . you don't have to copy all code. you have to get idea from it.

Comment: The text and buttons are now positioned well, only the text that is formed in to a link is not a link. It's just text under the other text, it's not clickable.

Comment: wait never mind, nothing changed. Everything is positioned well, the link just isn't there

Comment: Do you have any more answers that could help?